# NUMA and VM sizing on VMware

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I thought I understand how to right size VMs into NUMA slots but in this case I am getting more confused.
The virtual host(s) in questions are HP DL360 G10 with 2x Xeon Gold 6128 CPUs and 320GB of RAM. I have confirmed NUMA is enabled and I can confirm my NUNA node count is 4 by running:

```
esxcli hardware memory get | grep NUMA
```

So on ESXTOP NUMA/MB indicates again 4 NUMA nodes with an uneven amount of memory allocated to them. I would presume that is because of the total amount of memory? Although this can be split by 4 evenly?
If I would like to spec a particular large virtual machine within a NUMA node it could have 6 vCPUs (6 vCores on 1 vSocket) and it can either have 90GB or 60GB of RAM maximum?

Highlighted with a red square is a 12 vCPU (6 vCores on 2 vSockets) with 42GB of RAM. From the ESXTOP, my understanding is that is it spread across all 4 NUMA nodes. How can I see if this is an issue and if, in fact I could add more memory without causing more NUMA related performance issue? My understanding is that a virtual machine should not go beyond a NUMA boundary but in our case what would that be? The number in brackets at NUMA/MB indicates how much free memory is available per NUMA node but where are the stats for the CPU in regards to the NUMA nodes? Or can I just assume the 24 vCPU divided by 4 is the allocated vCPU amount per NUMA node?

The server in question is a Windows 2019 Standard Edition Server running as a Remote Desktop Host on vShpere 6.5.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you are using Vsphere 6.5 so you shouldn't think a lot about NUMA.
[check this link](https://blogs.vmware.com/performance/2017/03/virtual-machine-vcpu-and-vnuma-rightsizing-rules-of-thumb.html)